Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS breaks Chrome (apparmor issue)
Upgraded for the previous LTS to 24.04 LTS. Installed Chrome from Google .deb package, not through Ubuntu's apt repos or snap.
Since the Ubuntu upgrade Chrome fails to launch. Running it from the command line returns a hard error and terminates.
$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome
[###:FATAL:credentials.cc(131)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13) Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Chrome will run with --no-sandbox flag which is of course less safe.
sudo dmesg included entry like
apparmor="DENIED" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="Userns create restricted - failed to find unprivileged_userns profile" error=-13 profile="unconfined" pid=5054 comm="chrome" requested="userns_create" denied="userns_create" target="unprivileged_userns"
This points to an apparmor issue.
/etc/apparmor.d/chrome exists and matches what is some of the Ubuntu documentation at https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-23-10-restricted-unprivileged-user-namespaces . The path defined matches my chrome installation. Why doesn't this work?

After some research I checked the output of sudo aa-status and the chrome profile in /etc/apparmor.d/chrome (or in fact anything related to chrome) was not in the list.
Speculation: from my manual chrome installation, due to my Ubuntu upgrade, a combination of those factors or just bad luck, apparmor did not load the new profile from the Ubuntu upgrade.
From some further searching the following commands loaded the missing profiles and worked across reboots.
sudo systemctl enable apparmor
sudo systemctl start apparmor

This is probably not the way you're supposed to force a profile reload but it did just work(tm).
